# How can I integrate a rasa chatbot with a QA platform like stackoverflow for teams?

Tags: rasa, stackexchange

I need to integrate my developed chatbot with RASA with a question and answer platform like stackoverflow for teams version

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and actually ask a question.

Answer (score 1):

In RASA you can use custom actions to have custom python code handle an intent of a user. More information on this topic can be found [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/core/actions/).